# Is amazon providing any API to get product list rather than Advertising API

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am going to develop product price comparison app from the amazon products. Is amazon providing any API to get product list whatever they are showing on their website. Amazon providing advertisement API with minimum data like product name and review link, detail page link.  But I want those as data not as links. Is any API available. Example (www.91mobiles.com) like this I want to do. Is 91mobile crawling the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon does provide product advertising apis, below is the wsdl for same -

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl?rw_useCurrentProtocol=1
```

For details you should check [Amazon Product advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html). Please also need that to use it you should be registered as amazon affiliate.

Comment: Hi, I have tried their sample code and getting this error response
*Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include AssociateTag.* but in sample code they not using AssociateTag.

Comment: <Request>
<IsValid>False</IsValid>
<ItemLookupRequest>
<IdType>ASIN</IdType>
<ItemId>0545010225</ItemId>
<ResponseGroup>Small</ResponseGroup>
<VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
</ItemLookupRequest>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Code>AWS.MissingParameters</Code>
<Message>
Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include AssociateTag.
</Message>
</Error>
</Errors>
</Request>

Comment: You are missing some required parameter in request, if you need help regarding using the provided Api you should update question or you should create a new question that would attract better answers.